# custom bootstrap button color background erroneous onclick

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Within Twitter Bootstrap there is a selection of buttons that one can choose from (as seen here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html). For our project, we opted to use a yellow color that was not included in the default set. A simple matter to simply create a new css class which included the colors I wanted. However, when the button is pressed in, the background color returns to the default grey background color instead of a like-background color as is seen with the other buttons on click. Did I miss something during the creation of the button?

example of issue (taken in FF):

[image: button example]

Comment: post the css for your button.

Comment: The answer below got me to fix the issue. I was assuming that this block from the bootstrap code would have dealt with it, but apparently not:

`.buttonBackground(@startColor, @endColor) {
  ...
  &:hover, &:active, &.active, &.disabled, &[disabled] {
    background-color: @endColor;
  }
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify your new color with the :active pseudo selector. When you press a button it gets "active" and the :active selector kicks into play. When you release the mouse button the element stops being active and the element style reverts back to normal. Sort of like the :hover pseudo selector, when you're hovering the pointer over something.

Comment: Thanks Lars. I didn't think I had to manually set the :active since its already handled in the bootstrap code, but apparently I do.

Answer (score 0):

i found this question via google.
recommend a article,must do some help
**http://rubysource.com/how-to-customize-twitter-bootstrap%E2%80%99s-design-in-a-rails-app/**